# How to filter out alphanumeric values using regular expression in pig

Tags: regex, hive, apache-pig

Pig Code

```
relation2 =  filter relation1 by column1 not matches '.*[a-z0-9.*].*'
```

hive logic

```
column1 not like '%[a-z0-9]%'.
```

I want to implement the same logic in pig.

Comment: correction -  b not matches '.*[a-z0-9].*'

Comment: Aaaaand what's your question?

Comment: Hi Thomas, in my hive query I am filtering regular expression as - Column_name not like '%[a-z0-9]%'. I want to implement same logic in pig

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you don't need alpha numeric records.

you look for records that have either alphabets or numbers.

Could you try this :

Input :

```
(123AET)
(123)
(AET)
(236MET)
```

So your expected output is

```
 (123)
 (AET)
```

Pig Script : This script is a generic script from which you can  keep alphabets alone or number alone or alphanumeric alone or both  for further processing

```
records = LOAD '/home/dir/alphanumeric.txt' USING PigStorage(',') AS(c1:chararray);

records_each = FOREACH records GENERATE c1,  (REGEX_EXTRACT(c1,'(^[a-zA-Z]+$)',1) is not null ? 'ALPHABETS' : (REGEX_EXTRACT(c1,'(^[0-9]+$)',1) is not null ? 'NUMBERS' : 'ALPHANUMERICS')) as c1_type;

records_filter = filter records_each by c1_type in( 'ALPHABETS','NUMBERS');

records_output = foreach records_filter generate c1;

dump records_output;
```